# Compiling pyHook failed via swig under windows

Tags: python, gcc, mingw, swig, pyhook

**Note :**

> I just want pyhook 64 bit that's why doing all this because can't find any
>   64 bit version for Windows Link mentioned all over internet is this 
>   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook but I can't find from
>   here there are just .whl pakages few .exe but not pyhook

I tried to build it with the default compiler settings which is vs but it gives the error "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" I have added this to system variable but stills it shows error.

```
C:\Python27\pyHook-1.5.1>dir
 Volume in drive C is Window.!
 Volume Serial Number is FE06-94AB

 Directory of C:\Python27\pyHook-1.5.1

09/08/2015  02:32 AM    <DIR>          .
09/08/2015  02:32 AM    <DIR>          ..
02/23/2005  04:57 PM             1,761 aa hook.py
09/08/2015  02:43 AM    <DIR>          build
10/05/2008  09:47 PM             1,158 CHANGELOG.txt
10/05/2008  09:33 PM             8,614 cpyHook.i
09/08/2015  04:54 AM             2,934 cpyHook.py
09/08/2015  04:54 AM           128,186 cpyHook_wrap.c
02/23/2005  04:57 PM               302 doc.py
02/23/2005  04:57 PM             1,396 example.py
07/22/2008  08:09 PM            23,787 HookManager.py
12/05/2003  10:35 AM             1,064 LICENSE.txt
10/05/2008  09:43 PM               221 MANIFEST.in
10/05/2008  09:48 PM             1,172 PKG-INFO
10/07/2008  11:36 PM               842 README.txt
10/05/2008  09:36 PM             1,646 setup.py
09/13/2004  01:40 PM                25 __init__.py
              14 File(s)        173,108 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  43,204,739,072 bytes free

C:\Python27\pyHook-1.5.1>python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
copying cpyHook.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyHook
running build_ext
building 'pyHook._cpyHook' extension
swigging cpyHook.i to cpyHook_wrap.c
C:\swigwin-3.0.7\swig.exe -python -o cpyHook_wrap.c cpyHook.i
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Then I searched in previous answers here and found that I can also use other compilers, so I used mingw it also shows error

```
C:\Python27\pyHook-1.5.1>python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32
running build
running build_py
copying cpyHook.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pyHook
running build_ext
building 'pyHook._cpyHook' extension
swigging cpyHook.i to cpyHook_wrap.c
C:\swigwin-3.0.7\swig.exe -python -o cpyHook_wrap.c cpyHook.i
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
 -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c cpyHook_wr
ap.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\cpyhook_wrap.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-5.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\
\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: You're actually using mingw-w64, which is _not_ MinGW, but anyway, `-mno-cygwin` is an ancient cygwin specific feature, which hasn't been supported for years; any tool chain which is still specifying it automatically is either in desperate need of an upgrade, or, if it's already at it's current version, it's just plain broken. OTOH, if _you_ are specifying this defunct option yourself, then don't do that; use the appropriate (cross) compiler instead.